# Difference between SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS and SYS.ALL_TAB_COLS in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle12c, database-metadata, system-tables

What is the difference between the `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` and `ALL_TAB_COLS` system tables in Oracle 12c?  In my DB, the ALL_TAB_COLUMNS has slightly fewer rows than ALL_TAB_COLS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[From the Oracle manual for **ALL_TAB_COLS**](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-85036F42-140A-406B-BE11-0AC49A00DBA3.htm)

> *This view differs from "ALL_TAB_COLUMNS" in that system-generated hidden columns and invisible columns, which are user-generated hidden columns, are not filtered out.*

[From the Oracle manual for **ALL_TAB_COLUMNS**](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-F218205C-7D76-4A83-8691-BFD2AD372B63.htm)

> *This view filters out system-generated hidden columns and invisible columns, which are user-generated hidden columns. The ALL_TAB_COLS view does not filter out hidden columns and invisible columns*

Answer (score 0):

ALL_TAB_COLUMNS lists only user-defined columns whereas ALL_TAB_COLS also seems to contain some system columns in each user table that are not normally visible.