# How can i list schemas names from a database on Oracle and SQLServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I can list the schemas names with PostgreSQL for example using the query:

```
select schema_name from information_schema.schemata
```

What query is equivalent for Oracle and SQLServer? Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no `information_schema` in Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have definitely used INFORMATION_SCHEMA on at least one Oracle installation.  However, there were several others where I could not find/use it, so I was never sure what was going on (I don't know Oracle nearly as well as SQL Server).  Maybe it's only available as an add-on pack?

Comment: No, `information_schema` is most definitely not available in Oracle. Maybe you are confusing it with MySQL? Or someone in your organization wrote the views manually.

Comment: No it was definitely on a large Oracle11g customer installation that I worked on for over a year.  Maybe it was something like [this](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/Oracle/INFORMATION_SCHEMA/index) that one of their corporate DBAs installed?  I was working for one small department of a *huge* company that had pre-packaged corporate standard installations, so it might have been something that they mandated for their universal management tools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle equivalent of information\_schema.tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037468/oracle-equivalent-of-information-schema-tables)

Answer (score 0):

As of Oracle:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select * from all_users;

USERNAME                          USER_ID CREATED
------------------------------ ---------- --------
XS$NULL                        2147483638 29.05.14
MIKE                                   50 08.03.21
SCOTT                                  48 26.12.20
APEX_040000                            47 29.05.14
APEX_PUBLIC_USER                       45 29.05.14
FLOWS_FILES                            44 29.05.14
<snip>
```

Don't know about MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

connect to database using SQLdeveloper or SQL developer then run the below query to fetch schema details

SELECT *
FROM dba_users

Comment: _"connect to database using SQLdeveloper or SQL developer"_    Hmm.  What's the difference between 'SQLdeveloper' and 'SQL developer'?  How to choose which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

In theory this should work the same on both Oracle and SQL Server as it does on Postgres.  I know that it works on SQL Server, however on Oracle I vaguely recall that there's some trick or setting to access (or enable?) the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables.

Both Oracle and SQL Server also have their own custom system tables/views for stuff like this (`sys.schemas` for SQL Server and `dba_users` for Oracle, I think).  SQL Server treats Schemas and Users as independent objects (Users can own Schemas) whereas Oracle treats them as different attributes/features of the same object (User == Schema), I'm not sure how Postgres does it.

Also, both SQL Server and Oracle will apply security "hiding" to objects that you do not have privs to see, even through `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.  So if you are not supposed to be able to "View" a certain schema, then it won't appear to you in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` table either.  However, in many cases you are permitted to view metadata like this even when you are not permitted to access the objects themselves (depends on security settings).

Comment: For Postgres a user and a schema are two very different things