# Grab all columns except some

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table with a lot of columns (about 50). And also I've 5 columns which name starts with `expr_...`. I want to grab all columns except columns `expr_...`. Can I do it quick without defining all of needed columns?

Like:

```
SELECT
 * FROM TABLE WHERE column_name NOT LIKE '%EXPR%'
```

Instead of:

````
SELECT
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, .... FROM table```
````

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/55037544/16019058 I don't know if oracle has this functionality as others have with information_scema.

Comment: No, type your column names. (many tools do typing for you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL offers various options, most obvious being a function that returns ref cursor or custom type.

However, if you want to stay within pure SQL, you could write some code to write code for you. Here's how.

Sample table that contains several `expr_` columns:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2  select empno id, ename name, mgr, hiredate,
  3    job expr_1, sal expr_2, deptno expr_3
  4  from emp where rownum <= 5;

Table created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME              MGR HIREDATE  EXPR_1        EXPR_2     EXPR_3
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH            7902 17-DEC-80 CLERK            800         20
      7499 ALLEN            7698 20-FEB-81 SALESMAN        1600         30
      7521 WARD             7698 22-FEB-81 SALESMAN        1250         30
      7566 JONES            7839 02-APR-81 MANAGER         2975         20
      7654 MARTIN           7698 28-SEP-81 SALESMAN        1250         30
```

If you query `user_tab_columns`, concatenate keywords with aggregated list of *desired* columns (because `where` clause eliminates `expr` ones), result is what you need:

```
SQL> select 'select ' ||
  2    listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_id) ||
  3    ' from test' result
  4  from user_Tab_columns
  5  where table_name = 'TEST'
  6    and column_name not like 'EXPR%';

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select ID, NAME, MGR, HIREDATE from test
```

Finally, copy/paste above statement and just execute it:

```
SQL> select ID, NAME, MGR, HIREDATE from test;

        ID NAME              MGR HIREDATE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
      7369 SMITH            7902 17-DEC-80
      7499 ALLEN            7698 20-FEB-81
      7521 WARD             7698 22-FEB-81
      7566 JONES            7839 02-APR-81
      7654 MARTIN           7698 28-SEP-81
```

*Upgrade* previous statement to a `create view` so that you'd have it stored in the database and query it (the view) from now on:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_test as select ID, NAME, MGR, HIREDATE from test;

View created.

SQL> select * From v_test where name = 'SMITH';

        ID NAME              MGR HIREDATE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
      7369 SMITH            7902 17-DEC-80

SQL>
```

---

Here's the *function that returns ref cursor* option (if you think you want that instead; I wouldn't as it isn't that flexible as previously posted view option):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(1000);
  5    rc    sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    select 'select ' ||
  8      listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_id) ||
  9      ' from test'
 10    into l_str
 11    from user_Tab_columns
 12    where table_name = 'TEST'
 13      and column_name not like 'EXPR%';
 14
 15    open rc for l_str;
 16    return rc;
 17  end;
 18  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

        ID NAME              MGR HIREDATE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
      7369 SMITH            7902 17-DEC-80
      7499 ALLEN            7698 20-FEB-81
      7521 WARD             7698 22-FEB-81
      7566 JONES            7839 02-APR-81
      7654 MARTIN           7698 28-SEP-81


SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a procedure for this and execute immediate or output to the console for editing and later executing like so and replace `EXAMPLE` with your table name:

```
DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  v_sql := 'SELECT ';
  FOR col IN (
    SELECT column_name
    FROM all_tab_columns
    WHERE table_name = 'EXAMPLE'
      AND column_name NOT LIKE 'expr\_%' ESCAPE '\'
  ) LOOP
    v_sql := v_sql || col.column_name || ', ';
  END LOOP;
  -- Remove trailing comma and space
  v_sql := SUBSTR(v_sql, 1, LENGTH(v_sql) - 2);
  v_sql := v_sql || ' FROM EXAMPLE';
  -- Print or execute the constructed SQL query
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql); -- Use DBMS_OUTPUT for printing print
  -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql; -- Uncomment to execute the query
END;
```

It is pertinent to test thoroughly before executing any dynamically created query.

Alternatively just do this to get all column names to save on typing:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'EXAMPLE'
  AND column_name NOT LIKE 'expr\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```